# Where can be found P2P chat program sample code written in C# or C++ or VisualBasic?

Tags: c#, p2p

I need good tutorial and working code sample of P2P real-time chat program written on C#, C++ or Visual Basic.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/Chat_application_using_WC.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this(C#):
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx